# Convert an asset imported with Webpack to a File() or Blob() object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've got a video stored locally on my computer in a folder called `assets`. I'm importing the file currently like this into my project:

```js
import sample1 from './assets/sample1.mp4';
```

I want to use the file as a `File()` or `Blob()` object, however I do not know how I could convert the string path Webpack is giving me to one of those objects.

I am using React with `create-react-app`, so changing the Webpack configuration would not be ideal.

I thought the `FileReader()` object would solve my problem, however it only accepts `Blob()` objects.

Comment: Try converting it to a blob manually: `new Blob([ sample1 ], { type: 'video/mp4' })` - if the video is encoded in base64 this should result in a playable blob. Though if it's base64 you could also use directly as a source?

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly. I didn't know that you could pass the path, enclosed in an array, as an argument to the Blob() constructor.

Comment: The path is probably just a base64 string anyway. A blob can contain _any_ type of data, and the array is because you can use it combine multiple chunks of data. I've been using blobs for a bunch of stuff and its kinda fun :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using an ideal solution, however this works and the Webpack configuration does not need to be changed.

@somethingthere's solution would work, if the file would be directly imported as a base64 encoded string, however the Webpack configuration from `create-react-app` handles this differently and only the file path is contained in the imported variable. But I hadn't come to this solution without her/him.

1. I've converted my assets to base64 strings with [this tool](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file) and downloaded the strings as text files.
2. Opening the files crashed the "Text Editor" application on my Ubuntu machine, so I've copied the files to my clipboard with the following command: `cat base64.txt | xclip -selection clipboard`.
3. Then I converted the output to a data URL, just write the following text in front of your base64 string and make sure to change the data-type: `data:video/mp4;base64,YOURSTRING`.
4. For each asset I created a JavaScript file with a default export, which exports the created string.
5. Now you can import the data-url string and convert it to a Blob() as follows:

```js
async function convertToBlob() {
  const res = await fetch(MYIMPORT);
  const blob = await MYIMPORT.blob();
}
```

Done!

Comment: Pfwoa that is a process! Well done on finding the solution. I'm personally not a fan of webpack because of these things - or any bundlers really. Simply because they break the intended flow of files and then you constantly have to fight these solutions to get the desired result. One more note, but it _is_ better to _not_ include videos in a package like this. You now have megabytes and megabytes of data to be downloaded before the script can run, so maybe it's best to use the URLs anyway... Food for thought.

Comment: Luckily I only need this for testing purposes. It's for emulating the backend in development. But you are right, I should only import those assets, if the environment is set to development. Need to change that. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a blob using the `Blob` constructor as such:

```
const blob = new Blob([ value1 ], { type: 'video/mp4' });
```

The first argument is an array of chunks (of which you have 1, so one entry), the second is some metadata. By setting the type there it should read the data correctly. You can find out more at the docs about `Blob`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: Sadly, this does not work. It executes witout errors, however my file is always much smaller than the original video and can't be played in the browser. However, you definetely pointed me in the right direction!